# socket.io, node cluster, express, session store with redis

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, redis, socket.io

I'm not exactly sure how to describe this, but I'm running a node app with a cluster on 4 cores, port 80, using RedisStore as the socket.io store, express.js, and socket.io listens on it.

Some interesting behavior that happens is that on around 40% of clients that connect to socket.io using Chrome (and Firefox, but we stopped bothering using different browsers because it seems to be across the board), it connects and works fine for the first 25-30 seconds, then after that there is 60 seconds of dead time where requests are sent from the client but none are received or acknowledged by the server, and at 1.5 min - 1.6 min, the client starts a new websocket connection. Sometimes that new websocket connection has the same behavior, at other times the connection "catches" and is persistent for the next few hours and is absolutely fine.

What's funny is that this behavior doesn't happen on our test server that runs on a different port (which also uses a cluster); and moreover it doesn't happen on any of our local development servers (some of which implement clusters, others of which don't).

Any ideas?

Comment: I found a solution. Migrate away from socket.io back to ajax. It works.